# pandas : inconsitency in dtype while read_json with chunk

Tags: python, json, pandas, parquet, dask

**TL;DR**
What can be done to force the dtypes of the chunks read by pd.read_json ?

**Background**
I need to read a big dataset currently stored in line delimeted json, around 3 million lines.
I'm trying to cut it in small parquet files to be able to stream the full dataset with dask.

My basic idea was this:

```
_chunks =pd.read_json('data.json', lines=True, chunksize=5000)
i = 0
for c in _chunks:
   c.to_parquet('parquet/data.%s.pqt' % i)
   i = i+1

ddf = dataframe.read_parquet('parquet/*', index='_id')
ddf.compute()
```

But I get errors for some inconsistency in the dtypes, only for some partitions:

```
>>> ddf.get_partition(8).compute()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jai/usr/vendors/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 135, in compute
    (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jai/usr/vendors/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/base.py", line 333, in compute
    results = get(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jai/usr/vendors/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/threaded.py", line 75, in get
    pack_exception=pack_exception, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jai/usr/vendors/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 521, in get_async
    raise_exception(exc, tb)
  File "/home/jai/usr/vendors/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/compatibility.py", line 67, in reraise
    raise exc
  File "/home/jai/usr/vendors/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 290, in execute_task
    result = _execute_task(task, data)
  File "/home/jai/usr/vendors/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/local.py", line 271, in _execute_task
    return func(*args2)
  File "/home/jai/usr/vendors/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/io/parquet.py", line 335, in _read_parquet_row_group
    open=open, assign=views, scheme=scheme)
  File "/home/jai/usr/vendors/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fastparquet/core.py", line 284, in read_row_group_file
    scheme=scheme)
  File "/home/jai/usr/vendors/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fastparquet/core.py", line 334, in read_row_group
    cats, selfmade, assign=assign)
  File "/home/jai/usr/vendors/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fastparquet/core.py", line 311, in read_row_group_arrays
    catdef=out[name+'-catdef'] if use else None)
  File "/home/jai/usr/vendors/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/fastparquet/core.py", line 266, in read_col
    piece[:] = dic[val]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

So my insight was to force the dtype while reading the json before converting to parquet, and so did I.

**Edit**: I mean to force the float type instead of the automatic discovered int as NaN is a correct value for float but not for int

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pandas-big-data/) (the *Selecting Types While Reading the Data In* section) to make a good dtype dictionnary:

```
_index = ddf.dtypes.index

obj = 'object'
f64 = 'float64'
f16 = 'float16'
f32 = 'float32'
i64 = 'int64'
i16 = 'int16'
i32 = 'int32'
cat = 'category'

_new_types = [ obj, obj, f64, f64, obj, cat, i32, cat, cat, cat, cat, cat, cat, cat, obj, cat, f16, obj, f16, f64, f64, f64, f64, cat, f64, cat ]
_column_types = dict(zip(_index, _new_types))
_chunks =pd.read_json('data.json', lines=True, chunksize=5000, dtype=_column_types)
```

The problem is that when I check the chunks, they don't all have the same dtypes !

```
for c in _chunks:
    c.dtypes
    # print some columns as bool or int64 or object dependending of the chunk
```

Comment: seems like an issue in data.json

Comment: thx @RomainJouin
data.json is dumped from ElasticSearch, so I guess it is pretty standard...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the easiest thing that you can do here is to force the dtypes before writing. Since this doesn't appear to be working correctly with the `read_json` function, you could apply it thus

```
for c in _chunks:
c.astype(_column_types).to_parquet('parquet/data.%s.pqt' % i)
i = i+1
```

Note that I would consider 5000 records per parquet file to be much too small to make good use of the format. The typical size of each component parquet file is typically >>10MB.